# Can highcharts stacked percentage column chart be less than 100%

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a requirement to have a stacked percentage column chart in highcharts display a breakdown of a specific percentage number rather than a breakdown of 100%.  For example, if the number is 60%, the graph should show a breakdown of 60% (20% blue, 10% green, 30% yellow) rather than fill up to 100%. My understanding of percentage charts is they are always 100%, but wondering if this kind of manipulation is possible with highcharts somehow?  Thanks.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/pie-chart doesnt seem possible. Maybe you can tweek the css into making the remaining piece of pie disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm referring to a stacked percentage column chart actually http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent, not a pie chart.  I think in order for it to work, the total percentage number must be able to be edited in some way.  I don't think CSS can help here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what *@Alden Be* said, use stacked column with % labels.
Here is the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivien/6qpome6b/).

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'] 
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                },
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.total + '%';
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}%<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}%'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format:'{y}%',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Stacked column instead of stacked percentage column, then simply append a percent to your label. Percentage column automatically determines the percentages of all data points provided, it sounds like you want the column to instead simply render the provided information.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion, I was considering this earlier.  One thing I'm wondering, since the numbers are coming from a JSON file, and they have to be numbers, any idea how to append a percent to each label?